# Вычислить рабочее время между 2-мя датами

Tags: python, pandas

Имеется датафрейм с 4 колонками: Идентификатор задачи, Начальная дата, Конечная дата, часовой пояс.

```
EJ3232  28.02.2019 15:49    29.02.2019  08:49:38    Etc/GMT-3
EJ3233  01.03.2019 10:49    01.03.2019 15:49    Etc/GMT-4
EJ3234  02.03.2019 7:49 02.03.2019 18:49    Etc/GMT-5
```

И список выходных\праздничных дней.

```
'2024': {'1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 13, 14, 20, 21, 27, 28],
'2': [3, 4, 10, 11, 17, 18, 23, 24, 25],
'3': [2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 16, 17, 23, 24, 30, 31],
'4': [6, 7, 13, 14, 20, 21, 28, 29, 30],
'5': [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 18, 19, 25, 26],
'6': [1, 2, 8, 9, 12, 15, 16, 22, 23, 29, 30],
'7': [6, 7, 13, 14, 20, 21, 27, 28],
'8': [3, 4, 10, 11, 17, 18, 24, 25, 31],
'9': [1, 7, 8, 14, 15, 21, 22, 28, 29],
'10': [5, 6, 12, 13, 19, 20, 26, 27],
'11': [3, 4, 9, 10, 16, 17, 23, 24],
'12': [1, 7, 8, 14, 15, 21, 22, 29, 30, 31]}
```

Необходима функция которая вычисляла бы рабочее время с учетом выходных\праздничных дней и часового пояса.

Вот функция которую я пытаюсь адаптировать

```
#функция подсчета продолжительности

def WorkHours(row, name_start, name_end):

    start_date = row[name_start]
    end_date = row[name_end]
    
    #start_date = row['StartDate']
    #start_date = dt.datetime(start_date.year,start_date.month,start_date.day,start_date.hour,start_date.minute,start_date.second)
    #end_date = row['EndDate']
    #end_date = dt.datetime(end_date.year,end_date.month,end_date.day,end_date.hour,end_date.minute,end_date.second)
    
    #tb = row['TB_CM']
    tz = row['CM_TimeZone']
    end_hour = row['end_hour']
    start_hour = row['start_hour'] 
    DWD = 0
    
    
    
    if tz == 'Etc/GMT-10' :
        tstart = dt.time(3,0,0,0)
        tend = dt.time(11,0,0,0)
    elif tz == 'Etc/GMT-9' :
        tstart = dt.time(4,0,0,0)
        tend = dt.time(12,0,0,0)
    elif tz == 'Etc/GMT-8' :
        tstart = dt.time(5,0,0,0)
        tend = dt.time(13,0,0,0)
    elif tz == 'Etc/GMT-7' :
        tstart = dt.time(6,0,0,0)
        tend = dt.time(14,0,0,0)
    elif tz == 'Etc/GMT-6' :
        tstart = dt.time(7,0,0,0)
        tend = dt.time(15,0,0,0)
    elif tz == 'Etc/GMT-5' :
        tstart = dt.time(8,0,0,0)
        tend = dt.time(16,0,0,0)
    elif tz == 'Etc/GMT-4' :
        tstart = dt.time(9,0,0,0)
        tend = dt.time(17,0,0,0)
    elif tz == 'Etc/GMT-3' :
        tstart = dt.time(10,0,0,0)
        tend = dt.time(18,0,0,0)
    elif tz == 'Etc/GMT-2' :
        tstart = dt.time(11,0,0,0)
        tend = dt.time(19,0,0,0)
    elif tz == 'Etc/GMT-11' :
        tstart = dt.time(2,0,0,0)
        tend = dt.time(10,0,0,0)
    elif tz == 'Etc/GMT-12' :
        tstart = dt.time(1,0,0,0)
        tend = dt.time(9,0,0,0)
    else :
        tstart = dt.time(10,0,0,0)
        tend = dt.time(18,0,0,0)

    DWD = (pd.to_timedelta(end_hour) - pd.to_timedelta(start_hour)) 
    WH = pd.to_timedelta('0:00:00')
    #начало и конец периода к границам рабочего дня    
    if start_date.time()<tstart :
        start_date = dt.datetime(start_date.year,start_date.month,
                                 start_date.day,tstart.hour,0,0)
    
    if start_date.time()>tend :
        start_date=start_date+dt.timedelta(days=1)
        start_date = dt.datetime(start_date.year,start_date.month,start_date.day,tstart.hour,0,0)
    
    if end_date.time()<tstart :
        end_date=end_date-dt.timedelta(days=1)
        end_date = dt.datetime(end_date.year,end_date.month,end_date.day,tend.hour,0,0)

        
    if end_date.time()>tend :
        end_date = dt.datetime(end_date.year,end_date.month,end_date.day,tend.hour,0,0)
           
    
    if start_date>end_date:
        WH = pd.to_timedelta('0:00:00')   
    else:
        WH = pd.to_timedelta('0:00:00')
        startdelta = pd.to_timedelta(start_hour)
        enddelta = pd.to_timedelta(end_hour)
        
        #период укладывается в одни календарные сутки
        if start_date.date() == end_date.date(): 
            if len(cal[cal['Дата']==start_date.date()])==0:
                if start_date.date().isoweekday() in range(1,6):
                    WH = WH + DWD - pd.to_timedelta(start_date.strftime('%H:%M:%S') - startdelta) - pd.to_timedelta(enddelta - end_date.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
                elif start_date.date().isoweekday() in range(6,8):
                    WH = WH 
            else:
                t = cal[cal['Дата']==start_date.date()]['РВ'].iloc[0]
                if t ==0:
                    WH = WH
                else:
                    WH = WH + pd.to_timedelta(t, unit = 'h') - pd.to_timedelta(start_date.strftime('%H:%M:%S')- startdelta) - pd.to_timedelta(enddelta-pd.to_timedelta(1,unit = 'h') - end_date.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
                             
                
       #период не укладывается в одни календарные сутки         
        else:
            #первый день
            tabdate = cal[cal['Дата']==start_date.date()]
            if len(tabdate)==0:
                if start_date.date().isoweekday() in range(1,6):
                    WH = WH + DWD - pd.to_timedelta(start_date.strftime('%H:%M:%S')- startdelta)
                    
                elif start_date.date().isoweekday() in range(6,8):
                    WH = WH 
            else:
                t = cal[cal['Дата']==start_date.date()]['РВ'].iloc[0]
                WH = WH + max(pd.to_timedelta(t, unit = 'h')
                              - pd.to_timedelta(start_date.strftime('%H:%M:%S')- startdelta),
                              pd.to_timedelta(0, unit = 'h'))          
                
                
           #последний день 
            tabdate = cal[cal['Дата']==end_date.date()]
            if len(tabdate)==0:
                if end_date.date().isoweekday() in range(1,6):
                    WH = WH + DWD - pd.to_timedelta(enddelta - end_date.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
                    
                elif start_date.date().isoweekday() in range(6,8):
                    WH = WH 
            else:
                t = cal[cal['Дата']==end_date.date()]['РВ'].iloc[0]
                WH = WH + max(pd.to_timedelta(t, unit = 'h') - pd.to_timedelta(enddelta - end_date.strftime('%H:%M:%S')),pd.to_timedelta(0, unit = 'h'))
       
            period = pd.Series(pd.date_range(start_date.date()+pd.to_timedelta(1, unit = 'd'),
                                             end_date.date()-pd.to_timedelta(1, unit = 'd')))
            period = pd.to_datetime(period).dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") 
            cshort = period.loc[period.isin(calShort['Дата'])==True].count()
            indexes = period.loc[period.isin(calShort['Дата'])==True].index
            period = period.drop(indexes, axis = 0)
            indexes1 = period.loc[period.isin(calNull['Дата'])==True].index
            period = period.drop(indexes1, axis = 0)
            per1 = pd.DataFrame(period)
            per1['Day']=per1[0].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).date().isoweekday())
            WH = WH + pd.to_timedelta(per1.loc[(per1['Day']!=6) & (per1['Day']!=7)][0].count()*8,unit = 'h')+pd.to_timedelta(cshort*7,unit = 'h')        
    #  

    return WH
```

Comment: Без исходных данных, вашего кода (какой есть) и желаемого результата, боюсь, вам здесь не смогут помочь.

Comment: исходные данные в воспроизводимом виде, а не скриншотом.

Comment: В списках выходных, что за ключи '1', '2' и '3'?

Comment: В списках выходных, что за ключи '1', '2' и '3' это указание месяца

Comment: Мне достался этот код по наследству, и я не могу до конца его понять чтобы адаптировать в другом месте

Comment: По-моему проще код с нуля написать. Разбейте задачу на понятные вам шаги и делайте. Потом уже, когда будете понимать, какие шаги необходимы для решения этой задачи, пытайтесь понять доставшийся вам в наследство код, чтобы убедиться, что вы ничего не упустили или может подсмотреть какие-то решения для себя. Но без чёткого плана что вам нужно проделать с данными, анализировать чужой код почти бесполезно. Вы просто не будете понимать что и зачем там делается. И да, этот код ужасен, его рефакторить и рефакторить.

Comment: данные нужно чистить. например, `EJ3232  28.02.2019 15:49    29.02.2019` - 29 февраля в 2019 году - это нонсенс. где-то есть секунды, где-то нет. в остальном, можно составить алгоритм, в общем-то.

Comment: @insolor ОП привел свой календарь выходных дней. алгоритм можно реализовать. мне пока не ясно. как учитывать рабочее время, ведь, несмотря на указанные таймзоны, граница рабочего дня все равно не определены.

Comment: А надо ли учитывать, что, в предпраздничные дни, например, 7 марта, рабочий день сокращается на час?

Comment: Желательно учитывать сокращенные дни (думаю отдельным справочником) и обеденное время

Comment: Пока реализовал вот так (https://disk.yandex.ru/d/J7pnqCSfKXfMUQ)
Но этот код не учитывает сокращенные дни (пятница\предпраздничные) и обеденный перерыв
Буду рад если кто поможет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, алгоритм такой. при исходных данных:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

holidays = {'2019': {'1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 13, 14, 20, 21, 27, 28],
'2': [3, 4, 10, 11, 17, 18, 23, 24, 25],
'3': [2, 3, 8, 9, 10, 16, 17, 23, 24, 30, 31],
'4': [6, 7, 13, 14, 20, 21, 28, 29, 30],
'5': [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 18, 19, 25, 26],
'6': [1, 2, 8, 9, 12, 15, 16, 22, 23, 29, 30],
'7': [6, 7, 13, 14, 20, 21, 27, 28],
'8': [3, 4, 10, 11, 17, 18, 24, 25, 31],
'9': [1, 7, 8, 14, 15, 21, 22, 28, 29],
'10': [5, 6, 12, 13, 19, 20, 26, 27],
'11': [3, 4, 9, 10, 16, 17, 23, 24],
'12': [1, 7, 8, 14, 15, 21, 22, 29, 30, 31]}}

df = pd.DataFrame({"task":["EJ3232", "EJ3233", "EJ3234"],
                  "start":["27.02.2019 15:49", "01.03.2019 10:49", "02.03.2019 7:49"],
                  "end":["28.02.2019  08:49:38", "01.03.2019 15:49", "02.03.2019 18:49"],
                  "tz": ["Etc/GMT-3", "Etc/GMT-4", "Etc/GMT-5"]})
```

сначала приводим календарь выходных в удобный вид:

```
hc = []
for year in holidays.keys():
    for month in holidays[year]:
        for day in holidays[year][month]:
            hc.append(f"{year}-{month.zfill(2)}-{day:02d}")

hc = [pd.Timestamp(x) for x in hc]
```

затем временные промежутки с учетом начала, конца и временной зоны, и переводим их в серии:

```
df["ranges"] = df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(start=pd.to_datetime(x["start"], dayfirst=True, format='mixed').tz_localize(x["tz"]),
                            end = pd.to_datetime(x["end"], dayfirst=True, format='mixed').tz_localize(x["tz"]), freq="h"), axis=1)

dtranges = df.explode("ranges").drop(columns=["start", "end", "tz"])
dtranges["ranges"] = pd.to_datetime(dtranges["ranges"], utc=True)
```

затем выбираем только те дни, которые не являются выходными,
группируем по датам и номерам задач (можно только по задачам) и вычисляем продолжительность

```
bh_df = dtranges[~pd.to_datetime(dtranges["ranges"].dt.date).isin(hc)]
res = bh_df.groupby(["task", bh_df["ranges"].dt.date])["ranges"].apply(lambda x: x.max()-x.min())
```

получаем res, где в третьей колонке как раз продолжительность задачи за каждый день:

```
task    ranges    
EJ3232  2019-02-27   0 days 11:00:00
        2019-02-28   0 days 05:00:00
EJ3233  2019-03-01   0 days 05:00:00
Name: ranges, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

или, при

```
res = bh_df.groupby(["task"]).apply(lambda x: x.max()-x.min())
```

получим общее время выполнения задачи:

```
                ranges
task                  
EJ3232 0 days 17:00:00
EJ3233 0 days 05:00:00
```